# Why would anyone want an enemy to flee combat?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to use the fear spell over the calm spell?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42465/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-fear-spell-over-the-calm-spell)

I come across lots of weapons with an enchantment effect that makes certain-level enemies flee from combat for a period of time.  Why would anyone want to do this?  I haven't tried it myself, but I can only theorize that it does what it says it does:  When hit, enemy starts running in the opposite direction of the player for X seconds, after which it regains its desire to fight again.  Doesn't this just prolong what could otherwise be a much quicker fight?  Additionally, these enchanted weapons usually only work for lower-level enemies.  By the time you find them, you're up against much stronger enemies which would most likely be unaffected by the effect anyway.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly be a duplicate.  That question is asking about the advantages of one spell over another.  My question is about WHY you would want an enemy to flee combat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an enemy flees they won't be attacking allowing you to chase them down and kill them without having to worry about enemy attacks. This can work especially well in caves, ruins etc.

another scenario is when your surrounded by enemies, making some flee for a while could give you time to kill the others before killing them, instead of attacking them all at once.

There are various other combat strategies that you could use the flee enchantment with.

Answer (score 0):

Enemy level considerations aside, this is useful for anyone who works better at range. Specialized archers and mage come to mind. Anyone with low Health will want enemies not to hit them, too.